# Os dados não são registrados no banco de dados, mas aparece que o cadastro foi realizado com sucesso

Tags: php, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "tomorrow";
$conexao=@mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexao,$db) or die(mysqli_error());
?>

<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql=mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO usuarios(username, email, password)VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')");
echo "<center><h1>Cadastro realizado com sucesso</h1></center>";
mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Comment: Remova o `@` para verificar se há erros; A função `mysqli_error` após o método `mysqli_connect` está incorreta, o correto é `mysqli_connect_errno`; Após `mysqli_query` adicione `mysqli_error` para verificar se a `query` está correta; A mensagem está aparecendo pois você não adicionou um `if` para verificar se a `query` foi executada com sucesso; A função `mysqli_error` precisa do parâmetro `$conexão` etc.

Comment: nao tem como voce comentar com o codigo pra me ajudar mais por favor men

Comment: No banco o campo tá escrito "emai" e no PHP tá "email".

Comment: Por que você não testa a query antes de mostrar que foi inserido com sucesso? Usa as estruturas de controle pelo amor de G-ZUIS! E por que você está usando a tag center? Usa o marquee também.